# Killing with Kindness?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, foreign-phrases

Is there a name for the strategy of weakening your enemy via generosity, such that they become dependent upon your kindness and thereby unable to confront or disobey you?

Taking that one step further, is there a name for a similar strategy of providing your enemy with the knowledge and resources necessary for them to destroy themselves?

In the first case, I'm looking for an unconventional and academically advanced way that an extremely literate character might describe the actions of a drug-dealer or loan-shark.  In the second, that same character's assessment of a serial killer who uses psychological manipulation to induce suicide.

Comment: I can't think of an answer for the first part of your question, "killing with kindness" doesn't quite have the connotation of dependency and enslavement that you want. However an answer to the second part of your question could be "giving him enough rope to hang himself" or "giving himself enough room to trip himself up": although these are often used to talk about not stopping someone doing something reprehensible or illegal so that the evidence of their misdoings  becomes overwhelming.